# Segue Right, Segue Left throws: Application tried to present modally an active controller in Swift. why?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to segue left and right between my `VenueListVC` and `VenueDetailsVC`. But I am getting the following error: **`'Application tried to present modally an active controller <VenueDetailsVC: 0x104098980>.'`** when I segue back to the original VC using the `SegueFromLeft` segue with the assigned class.

I have the following classes; `SegueFromRight` which transforms and animates the destination VC from Right and the `SegueFromLeft` class just below it that aims to achieve something similar but rather from the Left-side by adding the '-' minus in `translationX: -src.view.frame.size.width`.

```
class SegueFromRight: UIStoryboardSegue {
override func perform() {
    let src = self.source
    let dst = self.destination

    src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)
    dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                   delay: 0.0,
                   options: .curveEaseInOut,
                   animations: {
                    dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
    },
                   completion: { finished in
                    src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
    )
}
```

}

```
class SegueFromLeft: UIStoryboardSegue {
override func perform() {
    let src = self.source
    let dst = self.destination

    src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)
    dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                   delay: 0.0,
                   options: .curveEaseInOut,
                   animations: {
                    dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
    },
                   completion: { finished in
                    src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
    )
}
```

}

I have the following `prepareForUnwind` IBAction in my `VenueListVC` (source VC)

```
@IBAction func prepareForUnwind (segue: UIStoryboardSegue){

}
```

I have used the exit point in `VenueDetailsVC` (destination VC) linked to the `prepareForUnwind` IBaction of the `VenueListVC` (source VC).

I have added the `SegueFromLeft` class to the segue.

[image]

Segue right works perfect, when I segue back it throws the error above but not before presenting the source VC.